# GtkEntry activated signal or activates default property?

Tags: events, user-interface, gtk

in a window with multiple `GtkEntry` widgets and `GtkButton` widgets which should be triggered when their corresponding `GtkEntry` is activated, should I switch which `GtkButton` is the default widget using the focus in signal or should I handle the activated signal of `GtkEntry` widgets directly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it would produce clearer code if you handled the `activated` signal of each entry directly.